# how to find the set of feasible optimal solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

Consider the following optimization problem;

$\min_{M} ~\|a-M*b\|_2$

subject to

$\|M\|_2<1$.

where $M\in R^{5\times3}$ and a and b are constant vectors.

There might be many optimal solutions to the problem above. I'm wondering if there's a theory/method to get the set of matrices M such that they all minimize the problem above.

Comment: Can you please tell me what do you mean with $||\cdot||_2$ ? The norm induced by $\ell^"$-norm, or maybe the Frobenius-norm ...?

Comment: I mean the $||M||_2$ norm! sorry

Comment: M is a matrix so $\|M\|_2$ means maximum singular value of M

Comment: The solution is not unique, in fact suppose you have found a matrix $M$, if you add to $m_j$ (j-th row of M) any vector orthogonal to $b$, than you still have a solution.

When $||b||_2\geq ||a||_2$, take $m_j= a_j\frac{b}{||b||_2^2}$ $\forall j$. This M realizes the very minimum (exactly in zero), in fact M can be expressed as $M=\frac{1}{||b||_2^2} a b^T$, now multiplying $M$ and $b$ you obtain $Mb=\frac{1}{||b||_2^2} a b^T b=\frac{1}{||b||_2^2} a||b||_2^2=a$.

The assumption ensures that $||M||_2\leq 1$.
But I'm interested to know how to do it when $||b||_2<||a||_2$.